# JS: get user in Chrome that is already logged in?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am developing a Chrome extension that uses a Google account to connect to calendar events. Previously, I used OAuth2 authentication to identify the user and obtain their access token. Now, I no longer need this separate authentication process. Instead, I want to sync my extension account with the Google account that I have already logged into in google calendar (which is sync for every google service on one session). Is it possible to do it this way?

I have logged in with OAuth2 but I want to take the session Chrome Google account instead:

[image]

Comment: It should happen automatically if you have `host_permissions` for google URLs used for authentication (like accounts.google.com or \*.google.com).